How to resolve CMakeLists.txt error in visual studio (ninja build error)
I am working on a project with an ESP32 WROOM32 and trying to use two UARTS, we can get the first one to work and output data, but the second one not so much. I am currently trying to compile my code and i ran into this error?
error:
CMake Error at C:/Users/DeLorenzoVincent/esp-idf/tools/cmake/component.cmake:451 (message):
  Called idf_component_register from a non-component directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (idf_component_register)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed

FAILED: build.ninja
C:\Users\DeLorenzoVincent\.espressif\tools\cmake\3.30.2\bin\cmake.exe --regenerate-during-build -SC:\Users\DeLorenzoVincent\esp-idf\Capstone -BC:\Users\DeLorenzoVincent\esp-idf\Capstone\build

 *  The terminal process "c:\Users\DeLorenzoVincent\.espressif\tools\ninja\1.12.1\ninja.exe" terminated with exit code: 1.

My CMakeLists.txt file is below:
# Minimum CMake version requirement
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30)

# Include ESP-IDF's project.cmake to use its build system
include(C:/Users/DeLorenzoVincent/esp-idf/tools/cmake/project.cmake)

#name 
project(Capstone)

# Register the components with their source files and include directories
idf_component_register(SRCS "uartEsc.c" "pid.c" "esc.c" "main.c" "i2c.c"
                       INCLUDE_DIRS ".")

I have tried using idf.py fullclean and building it
Verifying my versions are up to date
exporting and importing .\bat
and my main includes everything necessary

Next time please prefer to edit your question post instead of deleting it and re-asking again.

As for the error message, it seems to be pretty clear: You shouldn't call idf_component_register from the main CMakeLists.txt file. You may call that function from a CMakeLists.txt which is located in the component directory. By default, it is component/. You may want to revise the guide about writing ESP-IDF projects in CMake: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html
